# Usage of "accrue" in "it accrued to me to gently ask"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-usage, errors, transitivity

A newage hippie Facebook friend just sent me this. I was just wondering if it was syntactically correct,

> It accrued to me to gently ask if you could consider extending the same respect, you would obviously extend to this man, to Theists in general.

*Accrue* is supposed to be a transitive verb, it doesn't seem to be operating on something though. I take it, this is incorrect? Or, am I wrong?

Comment: You need to have FB friends who have accrued enough to have phones with better autocorrect ;)

Answer (score 10):

Your friend most likely meant that it *occurred* to them. *Accrued* is a [mondegreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen): a language mistake based on similar-sounding words.

Comment: Or, perhaps, an auto-correct failure.

Comment: Thus, perhaps, an auto-accrue failure.

Comment: I agree that it is a probable mistake, but I'm not certain it is for _occurred_. In context it probably is that, but my first thought on reading the phrase was that it was a novel metaphorical extension rather than a mishearing: _accrued to me_ meaning _became part of my property_, so meaning something like _it became my task to ask_.